# How to uninstall npm package which is inside onother npm package

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobile-development, react-native-instagram-login

I install this react-native-instagram-login package which contain react-native-webview this package so I want to uninstall react-native-webview this one because I already installed it in my react native project and its give me error -> Tried to register two views with the same name RNCWebView.

Comment: package managers like npm/yarn should already be managing the duplicates based on version etc., why do you want to uninstall it?

Comment: check if the dependency versions match.  if not, try to upgrade/downgrade your dependency's version to match theirs

Comment: https://docs.npmjs.com/uninstalling-packages-and-dependencies

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can try this command in your case

> `npm uninstall react-native-webview`
> or
> `npm uninstall --save react-native-webview`
> or if its a **devDependency** then
> `npm uninstall --save-dev react-native-webview`